# What rails libraries are for network connections like http and ftp

Tags: ruby

What rails gems are used for things like http requests (get, post) and for connecting to a ftp server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The de-facto library is Net::HTTP and Net::FTP (respectively), but there are a number of better ones out there. Check out this fairly inclusive feature matrix to see which one fits your needs best:

[Ruby HTTP Clients – Feature Matrix/Table](https://spreadsheets0.google.com/pub?hl=en&hl=en&key=0AiZsKd8d4hSJdHFFbjR5aWNjWjlzWlhiNGxQejdBWWc&output=html)

Answer (score 1):

Coreyward is correct.

If you find that you need to go lower-level, you can also look into socket programming.

Ex:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm

Answer (score 1):

I am using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) to working with web-services.